# If ANY text field (of the same class) has text, enable submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I've been banging my head over and over again trying to get this to work. I'm still relatively new at Javascript.

I have multiple text fields in a form that share the same class, ".donation". I have a submit button that is disabled by default:

```
<button type="submit" value="submit" id="continue" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Continue »</button>
```

I need it so that if ANY of the ".donation" text fields have text in them, the submit button becomes enabled.  The text fields only accept numbers.

I have tried several different scripts to no avail.  I mostly see scripts that check if the entire form has been filled in, or if a single text field has been filled in.  But again, what I need is just one--any--of the ".donation" fields to be filled in order to enable the submit button.

My last couple attempts include the following:

```
$(':text').keyup(function() {
if($('.donation').val() != "") {
   $('#continue').removeAttr('disabled');
} else {
   $('#continue').attr('disabled', true);   
}
});
```

This one only detected if the first ".donation" field was filled and ignored all those that followed.

Then I tried adding a .each value:

```
$(':text').keyup(function() {
    $('.donation').each(function() {
        if($('.donation').val() != "") {
           $('#continue').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
           $('#continue').attr('disabled', true);   
        }
    });
});
```

This one had the same result.

Any help would be great! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter the inputs based on value to see if any of them have a value, then set the `disabled` **property** based on that.

```
var inputs = $('.donation');

inputs.on('keyup', function() {
    var hasInput = inputs.filter(function() {
                       return $.trim(this.value).length > 0;
                   }).length;

    $('#continue').prop('disabled', !hasInput);
});
```

```js
var inputs = $('input[type="text"]');

inputs.on('keyup', function() {
    var hasInput = inputs.filter(function() {
                       return $.trim(this.value).length > 0;
                   }).length;

    $('#continue').prop('disabled', !hasInput);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>A value in any input will enable the button</p>
<br />
<input type="text" /><br/>
<input type="text" /><br/>
<input type="text" /><br/>
<input type="text" /><br/>
<input type="text" /><br/>
<br/><br/>
<button type="submit" value="submit" id="continue" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Continue »</button>
```

Comment: Probably a micro-optimization, but you could make it slightly more efficient by first checking the field that fired the event in the first place. If it's not blank, you can avoid having to check any of the other fields. Of course, if it is blank, you still need to check the others.

Comment: YES! This one works so long as I do the inputs = $('.donation'). I have a search field on the page as well, so if I do the 'input[type-"text"]' it won't ignore the search.  THANK YOU!

Comment: @MattBurland - The optimized version would be something like this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/bagzd1p7/**

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer to current item in `each`:

```
$('.donation').each(function() {
if($(this).val() != "") {  // $(this) will get current element object on which iterating
   $('#continue').removeAttr('disabled');
   return false; // break the loop of found element that has value in it
} else {
   $('#continue').attr('disabled', true);   
}
});
```

Comment: return? you mean return false, right? and you need an event too